# New memory limit in XCode 15?

Tags: c, xcode, memory

I am coding in C using XCode, and I have recently upgraded to XCode 15.0.

My code uses very large arrays, for example 35000x20000x3 of int.

This was never an issue in the previous version of XCode, but now my code crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

When I reduce the size of the arrays to 4500x4500x3, the code runs fine. At this size, the activity monitor says my program needs about 930MB of memory. If I increase the size of the arrays by a small amount, the code crashes. It seems like XCode is not allowing me more than 1GB of memory.

Unfortunately, my application needs the very large arrays.

I have tried Googling the problem, read the release notes and looked for an answer here on stackoverflow, but without success.

My MacBook is 64 bit with 64GB memory running Sonoma 14.0.

Thanks for any pointers! (Is there a compiler parameter for increasing memory?)

Comment: Have you looked at `ulimit(1)` and/or `getrlimit(2)` / `setrlimit(2)`? My _guess_ is that the soft limit (default) was reduced. I'd call `getrlimit` just before doing the heavy `malloc` call.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. getrlimit returns 2^63-1 for data, which is huge.